# Examine if the positive cones $C_{+}[a,b]$ and $c_{0}^{+}$ of $C[a,b]$ and $c_{0}$ have interior points

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Question**: Examine if the positive cones $C_{+}[a,b]$ and $c_{0}^{+}$ of $C[a,b]$ and $c_{0}$ have interior points.

As of now I have only worked for the positive cone of $C[a,b]$. I have found the following theorem which might help me.

**Theorem**

If E is a Banach space ordered by the closed cone P and $x_0 \in P$ then the following are equivalent:

i) $x_0$ is an order unit of E

ii) $x_0$ is an interior point of P

I begin working on the question by trying to show firstly that $C_{+}[a,b]$ is a closed cone of $C[a,b]$. I managed to show that $C[a,b]$ is closed but I am not sure how to continue. Also, I believe that my approach is not correct since the question says to examine IF the cones have interior points but what I am currently doing is trying to prove that there are interior points since I am trying to use the above theorem.

Does anyone have any guidelines on how to approach this question? Thank you.

*Edit* - *Definitions*

$C[a,b] = \{f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} |$ f is continuous$\}$

$C_{+}[a,b] = \{f \in C[a,b] | f(x) \geq 0 \forall x \in [a,b] \}$

$c_0 = \{(a_n) | a_n \rightarrow 0 \}$ (set of all sequences converging to zero)

$c^+_0 = \{(a_n) \in c_0 | a_n \geq 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (I am not sure this is the definition but I believe it is correct)

**Interior element**

Let A be a set. An element $x \in A$ is called an interior point of A if $\exists r>0$ s.t. $B(x,r) \subseteq A$

where $B_X(x,r) = \{y \in X |  \hspace{0.5cm} \|y-x\|_X \lt r\}$

Comment: Please define the terms used in the question.

Comment: @zhw. I have added some definitions. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: What is an order unit of $\mathbb R^+$?  $C^+([a,b])$ has interior points and an order unit. If you found this, you will see that the same argument fails for $c_0$, and then you should have a proof.

Comment: @daw Thank you for the reply. So this means that both $C^+([a,b])$ and $c_0$ have interior points? I will look into it (tomorrow because I have to sleep!)

Comment: no, only one of them...

Comment: @daw oh you said fails. Okay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be easier to bypass the general result you mentioned.

$C_+[a,b]:$ Let $f_0(x)=1$ for all $x\in [a,b].$ Then $B(f_0,1/2) \subset C_+.$ Proof: Suppose $f\in B(f_0,1/2).$ Then

$$f(x) = f_0(x) + f(x)-f_0(x)= 1 + f(x)-f_0(x)$$ $$\ge 1 - |f(x)-f_0(x)| > 1-1/2 =1/2$$

for all $x\in [a,b].$ This shows $B(f_0,1/2) \subset C_+[a,b].$ Hence $C_+[a,b]$ has interior points.

$c_0^+:$ This one has no interior points. Sketch of proof: Suppose $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ and $B(a,r)\subset c_0^+.$ Then $a-(r/2)e_n\in c_0^+$ for every $n.$ But since $a_n\to 0,$ $a_n-r/2 < 0$ for large $n.$ For such $n,$ $a-(r/2)e_n\notin c_0^+,$ contradiction.

Comment: What would $e_n$ be?

Comment: $e_n$ is the sequence with $1$ in the $n$th slot and $0$'s elsewhere.

Comment: I understand your answer now. Thank you very much. I wouldn't think of this approach right away. Do you have any advice on how to approach Mathematical Analysis problems in general? I know practice helps a lot for sure.